# Rails populate edit form for non-column attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have the following form:

```
<% form_for(@account, :url => admin_accounts_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

    <%= render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f} %>

    <h2>Account Details</h2>
    <% f.fields_for :customer do |customer_fields| %>
    <p>
        <%= customer_fields.label :company %><br />
        <%= customer_fields.text_field :company %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= customer_fields.label :first_name %><br />
        <%= customer_fields.text_field :first_name  %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= customer_fields.label :last_name %><br />
        <%= customer_fields.text_field :last_name  %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= customer_fields.label :phone %><br />
        <%= customer_fields.text_field :phone  %>
    </p>
    <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

As well as

```
attr_accessor :customer
```

And I have a before_create method for the account model which does not store the customer_fields, but instead uses them to submit data to an API.. The only thing I store are in the form partial..

The problem I'm running into is that when a validation error gets thrown, the page renders the new action (expected) but none of the non-column attributes within the Account Detail form will show?

Any ideas as to how I can change this code around a bit to make this work me??

This same solution may be the help I need for the edit form, I have a getter for the data which it asks the API for, but without place a :value => "asdf" within each text box, it doesn't populate the fields either..

Comment: When you take a newly created valid account (@account) and type @account.customer.company, what do you get as a result?

Comment: Well.. I'm not sure what the getter should do, right now what you asked returns a string containing the company name. BUT, in the sense of the NEW form, that customer isnt created yet, so I cant get that info from the API, therefor compaany needs to come from the params hash, not the api..

Comment: Right, so what happens when you make a call to @account.customer.company where the API integration has not happened yet? Do you still get a value if you have set it in the initializer but not in the API?

Comment: This is basically what I'm asking, what do I need to do to accomodate both the valid API call, and the new_record? Because I have a getter for this property obviously which handles the API call, but since it looks to the getter, I need the getter to return the correct portion of the params hash if new_record? no?

Comment: It might be helpful if you include some of the code you use for customer and it's attributes. My guess is that you aren't supporting the case where the API hasn't been interacted with yet, in which case you can't populate the default values because they don't exist in the API. If you provide some model code it might be easier to help you out here.

Comment: I dont have the code, thats what I'm asking for.. the getter just calls the api - what i need help with is how to create a getter that returns the params hash on new_record, and hits the API otherwise

Comment: http://cl.ly/0N1d0h3t241l1n1m0O1a here is model i have now, but it gets a stack level too deep because its calling itself.. if I take out the first line it still doesnt work even for the edit form..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, what you need to do is create a class to handle your customer with and without a Braintree gateway connection. First, create the class:

```
class Customer
  attr_accessor :company, :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :gateway

  def initialize gateway_id=nil
    begin
      @gateway = Braintree::Customer.find(gateway_id) unless gateway_id.nil?
    rescue Braintree::NotFoundError
    end
  end

  def company
    @gateway.nil? ? @company : @gateway.company
  end

  # Implement the rest of the methods this way as well. You can even use
  # meta-programming so that you don't repeat yourself.
end
```

You'll notice that calling Customer.new(id).company will work with and without an id or gateway, because if a gateway non-existent @company will be returned, and if a gateway is present the gateway's company will be returned.

Finally, hook this into your model:

```
class Account
  def customer
    @customer ||= Customer.new(self.gateway_customer_id)
  end

  def customer= h
    @customer = Customer.new
    @customer.company = h[:company]
    ...
    @customer
  end
end
```

You'll have to modify how you write code to the API so that you use customer.company instead of customer[:company] for example, but you can probably write a function within the Customer class to do this easily.

You'll have to modify your form to:

```
<% f.fields_for :customer, @account.customer do |customer_fields| %>
```

Comment: This makes sense for the most part.. but when looking at my forms, edit for instance, the fields are still empty..

Comment: I'm guessing my form has to change?

Comment: Have you tried fields_for @account.customer in your form? My guess is that, that object might not be properly initialized with the form helpers.

Comment: That's what I had done.. Figured it out though, I tried inheriting from Hash before just getting it working, without inheriting from Hash it works

Comment: Cool. Glad it worked out. I'll remove the hash inheritance from my answer.

Comment: So the edit action works, but I'm still working on new action, if you submit with an error, when the page renders the values in those fields do not get re-populating.. playing with it right now

Comment: @Rabbott - I added the correct fields_for call to my answer. Please try using that, it should give you the set value for your customer.

Comment: Oh.. check this out. When I submit the form with errors the field names change, which is why they don't get populated. http://cl.ly/072z2V0E3G070W252e25

Comment: I think you are defining your Customer class or fields_for incorrectly. See my example. I was able to get mine to work with validation errors: <input id="foo_bar_company" name="foo[bar][company]" size="30" type="text" value="BBC">

Comment: What is @customer? wouldnt this just be an empty object? (defined in your Account model)

Comment: @customer is an instance variable inside of @account accessible via @account.customer, but it has all the data from the API or the input values that the user typed in, so it's used to populate the defaults.

Comment: Hmm ok.. still not working with invalid input.. ill keep trying and let you know what comes out of it.

Comment: @pan-thomakos here is my Customer model http://pastie.org/1587210, Account model http://pastie.org/1587216, and the form http://pastie.org/1587218  ---- do these look somehow different than yours?

Comment: You are missing a setter for customer in account, so the customer is getting set to a hash instead of a Customer instance. Please see my updated answer. I added the setter for you. Thanks for sharing the code. Made debugging much easier :)

Comment: You win! Thank you for sticking with me, I REALLY appreciate it